# CSS: "Attribute selector" and "not()" together

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following rule:

```
a:not(.ui-spinner-button):active 
{
  ...
}
```

I would like a more general rule specifying that "style must applied to all A tag that does NOT have a class name that begin with 'ui-' ".

So, I should "merge" this kinf of definition `[class*='ui-']` with `not()`.

Is possible in some way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just put `[class*='ui-']` inside a `not()`.

```
a {
    color: cyan;
}

a:not([class*='ui-']) {
    color: pink;
}

<a class='ui-foobar'>ui-foobar</a>
<a class='foobar'>definitely not ui-foobar</a>
```

The first link will be cyan, the second one pink.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PW3f7/)